# ASIO write operation throws std::bad_alloc : C++

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am referring to [Chat Client](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/src/examples/cpp03/chat/chat_client.cpp)

My write Operation is:

```
void CSession::beginWrite(const Buffer & message)
{
    //Check if the socket is open or not?
    bool writeInProgress = !writeQueue_.empty();
    writeQueue_.push_back(message);
    if (!writeInProgress) //Exception Thrown here
    {
        asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(writeQueue_.front().received_, writeQueue_.front().buffsize),
            std::bind(&CSession::handle_write, this,
            std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }
}

void CSession::handle_write(const asio::error_code& error /*error*/, size_t bytes_transferred /*bytes_transferred*/)
{
    //std::cout << "CSession::handle_write() Called" << "(" << __FILE__ << " : " << __LINE__ << ")" << std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
        //std::cout << bytes_transferred << " bytes written to the socket." << std::endl;
        writeQueue_.pop_front();
        if (!writeQueue_.empty())
        {
            asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(writeQueue_.front().received_, writeQueue_.front().buffsize),
                std::bind(&CSession::handle_write, this,
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Write Error Detected" << std::endl;
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        state_ = false;
        doClose();
        return;
    }
}
```

It works fine. Then I tried load testing by making client write message `Client 2` to the server continuously for 11 minutes as shown below:

```
bool flag = false;

void setFlag(const asio::error_code& /*e*/)
{
    flag = true;
}

void Client(std::string IP, std::string port)
{
    CSession Session(IP, port);
    Session.initSession();

    asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &(*CIOService::fetchIOService().getIO())));

    asio::deadline_timer timer(*CIOService::fetchIOService().getIO(), boost::posix_time::seconds(675));
    timer.async_wait(&setFlag);

    while (!flag)
    {
        Session.write("Client 2");
    }

    Session.close();
    t.join();
}



void main()
{
    Client("localhost", "8974");
    system("Pause");
}
```

After 2-3 minutes of successful write operation, the code throws exception `Unhandled exception at 0x75B7C42D in NetworkComponentsClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x026DE87C.`  at line

`if (!writeInProgress) //Exception Thrown here
        {
            asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(writeQueue_.front().received_, writeQueue_.front().buffsize),
                std::bind(&CSession::handle_write, this,
                std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        }`

Debug shows:

```
-       writeQueue_ { size=16777215 }   std::deque<channel::Buffer,std::allocator<channel::Buffer> >
+       [0] {received_=0x052a0ac8 "Client 2" }  channel::Buffer
+       [1] {received_=0x052a0b28 "Client 2" }  channel::Buffer
+       [2] {received_=0x052a0b88 "Client 2" }  channel::Buffer
....
....
```

I can see size of `writeQueue_  { size=16777215 }` which is very large and hence `std::bad_alloc`.

Why such behaviour? I can see the code popping messages from deque as below:

`if (!error)
        {
            writeQueue_.pop_front();
            if (!writeQueue_.empty())
            {
                asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(writeQueue_.front().received_, writeQueue_.front().buffsize),
                    std::bind(&CSession::handle_write, this,
                    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
            }
        }`

So `write deque` should not have grown so large.

My client is supposed to run for days and should be involved large continuous data write. How do I ensure smooth long write operations?

Comment: You're queuing up messages as fast as you can in a tight loop but the network stack won't be able to go that fast, so the queue grows and grows. We don't know how your `Buffer` class is structured but presumably each instance uses a bit of memory, which all adds up. You'll need to add some rate limiting if you want to make this a real-world test.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Buffer is character array -  
 `struct Buffer
 {
  enum { buffsize = 32 };
  char received_[buffsize];
  Buffer(){}
  Buffer(std::string str)
  {
   //Truncate if Overflow
   auto len = str.size();
   if (len >= buffsize)
   {
    len = buffsize - 1;
   }
   std::copy(str.begin(), str.begin() + len, received_);
   received_[str.size()] = '\0';
  }
 };`  I suppose this is the simplest buffer I can make.Do you have better buffer structure idea, for better performance?

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer (`CSession`) is far slower than your producer (`Client`).
Your producer is doing a denial of service attack by producing messages as fast as it can. This is a good test.

Your consumer should (at least one, ideally all):

- detect that the work is accumulating and set up a policy when such things happen, like "ignore new", "drop oldest"
- Limit the consumption lag from happening by setting an active filter on incoming messages
- Improve the performance of incoming messages handling.

> My client is supposed to run for days and should be involved large
>   continuous data write. How do I ensure smooth long write operations?

Then you need a much better code than an example found online.